# TQBF as interactive game

Tags: terminology, logic

My teacher describes [true quantified boolean formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TQBF) (TQBF) as an interactive game between two players $\exists$ and $\forall$, and asks us to show a winning strategy for the existential player $\exists$. Can someone describe what this game is? I feel like this is background knowledge I am missing.

Comment: Have you tried asking the TA (for instance)?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Imagine the formula in some (prenex) normal form and consider the order of quantifiers: $\exists x_1 \forall x_2 \exists x_3 \exists x_4 \dots Q x_t \phi(\overline{x})$.  Let the player corresponding to the first quantifier choose its valuation (true or false) and then continue the game with that variable $x \mapsto v$ where $v$ is the value chosen for $x$, and with the first quantifier removed from the formula, i.e., in the example, if $\exists$ chooses true, let $x_1 \mapsto \mathtt{true}$ and continue the game on $\forall x_2 \exists x_3 \exists x_4 \dots Q x_t \phi(\overline{x'})$.

Let $\exists$ be the winner (as usual) if and only if the end result is a quantifier-free true formula.

Answer (score 3):

TQB formulae are in [prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form), so all quantifiers are at the beginning of the formula. Try and read such a formula from left to right:

$\qquad \forall w. \exists x. \forall y. \exists z. P(w,x,y,z)$

translates to

> for every $w$ there is an $x$ so that for every $y$ there is a $z$, so that $P$ is fulfilled.

Reading like it like a game goes like this:

- $\forall$ chooses arbitrary $w$.
- $\exists$ has to come up with a fitting $y$.
- Out of all values still remaining, $\forall$ chooses arbitrary $y$.
- Finally, $\exists$ has to come up with $z$ so that the predicate is fulfilled.

In general form that does not make too much sense; have a look at the [Pumping lemma](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) as a concrete example, which is often taught like a game. Another similar type of game is the [Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game).